# Right Join could not return all rows from the second table

Tags: mysql

My code doesn't return all the candidates who had no vote in the ballots table. It is supposed to return the details of all candidates who had vote or had no vote. But if i remove  `COUNT(choice) as votes`  from the query, it works perfectly.
how can I add the  `COUNT(choice) as votes` and still fetch the details of those that had no votes and votes?

```
SELECT  candidates.name as cname,COUNT(choice) as votes 
FROM ballots
RIGHT JOIN candidates 
ON candidates.id = ballots.candidate_id 
WHERE candidates.position_id ='1' 
GROUP BY ballots.candidate_id  
ORDER BY votes DESC
```

##### Candidates table

| id | name | Position_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Solomon | 1 |
| 2 | addai | 1 |

##### Ballots table

| voter_id | position_id | candidate_id | choice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |

##### results

| voter_id | votes |
| --- | --- |
| Solomon | 0 |
|  |  |

#### instead of:

##### results

| voter_id | votes |
| --- | --- |
| Solomon | 0 |
| Addai | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this query, you will get the expected result:

```
select candidate.name as voter_id, (select count(ballots.choice) from ballots WHERE ballots.candidate_id=candidate.id) as votes FROM candidate left JOIN ballots ON candidate.id = ballots.candidate_id WHERE candidate.position_id=1
```